# NLA strip disappeared after I edited dope sheet - Animation no longer works

Tags: dopesheet

The NLA strip disappeared after I edited the dope sheet. I've saved the file and opened it again but there's still no strip. Now my armature follows the path but it doesn't do the walk cycle like it did before.

[image]

Comment: can't you find the action in the Dopesheet if you switch it to Action Editor mode?

Comment: No, it's gone. It got erased and I'm starting again from the last saved version. This is such buggy software but I'm amazingly fortunate for your input. Thank you.

Comment: it's not buggy at all  ;)  you must have done something wrong but it's hard to tell, but at the beginning it's hard to understand how it works for sure

Comment: You can create new file and then Append the information from the old .blend file piece by piece.